# Get name and size for each hard drive partition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written code which lists me all drive letters used on my PC. How can I get the name, the total size, the free space and the already used space of each of these drives? (I am using Python 3.7)

My code:

```
import os
import string

drives = ['%s:' % drive + '\\' for drive in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:' % drive)]
```

Comment: Hi hngchris and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll have more luck with this question if you let us know what results you're getting, what else you've tried and similar details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3.3 and above, you can use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html) module, which has a `disk_usage` function, returning a named tuple with the amounts of total, used and free space in your hard drive.

```
import shutil

total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")

print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2**30))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to get the partition information as well.
You have to install the module (`pip install psutil`)
Once you get the partition information you can use `disk_usage` function, which is running the same script as `shutil` module to get the spcae information of each partition.

```py
import psutil

for disk in psutil.disk_partitions():
    if disk.fstype:
        print(disk.device, psutil.disk_usage(disk.mountpoint))
```